# scanf doesn't work properly for third time

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to write a simple C program. The input format is like this:

```
Enter a: <a>
```

I want to input a, b, c and d but the scanf doesn't work for c and d and the program crashes on that point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int a, b, c, d;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter a:");
    scanf("%c%d%c", &ch, &a, &ch);
    printf("Enter b:");
    scanf("%c%d%c", &ch, &b, &ch);
    printf("Enter c:");
    scanf("%c%d%c", &ch, &c, &ch);
    printf("Enter d:");
    scanf("%c%d%c", &ch, &d, &ch);
    double ans;
    ans=(a*b/c + c*d/a)/(b*a/c + d*b/a);
    ans=fabs(ans);
    printf("Formula 1 result = <%lf>", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing `int` pointer to `scanf` with the format `%lf` that expects a pointer to `double`.

Comment: the input format is like this: Enter a: <a>

Comment: yes I was wrong but that was't the problem. it doesn't work now too.

Comment: At what point does it crash now.

Comment: Note that the arithmetic is all done as integer arithmetic; the integer result is finally converted to a double.  That's probably not what you wanted.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `%c%d%c` notation?  If you type `1` as the first input, you'll have to type another number after it to be stored in `a`.  Yes, the second `%c` probably eats the newline after the number, but that's hardly critical since `%d` skips white space, including newlines, anyway.  You should be checking the value returned by `scanf()`; if it isn't 3 each time, something went wrong.  You should print the input values to confirm that the program got what you expected.  For my money, lose the `%c` conversion specifications and the `&ch` arguments to `scanf()`.

Comment: from this point: scanf("%c%d%c", &ch, &c, &ch); The scanf doesn't work for c and d.

Comment: What values are you entering?  What form does the crash take?  Note that given the formats used, you cannot enter single digit numbers.  If you enter double-digit numbers, the leading digit is removed.  If you try to enter a single digit number, followed by a return (newline), you have to enter the number (again) on the next line of input.

Comment: I wrote this(%c%d%c) because the input is like his:<1>. The "<" are characters that i don't want to use but the input format is like this.

Comment: Oh, so you're typing `<1>`?  Why?  That seems like pointless makework.  You don't enforce that the user enters the angle brackets; you don't make sure that they entered the correct angle brackets.  You don't prompt if the data comes from a file — files don't pay attention to prompts.

Comment: after entering b it prints: Enter c:Enter d: without getting any of them. I meant does't work properly by crash not an error

Comment: I have to submit this code and a machine will judge so i can't change the input format!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 format conversion specifiers which do not skip leading white space.  They are `%c` (which you're using), `%[…]` scansets, and `%n`.

When you type:

```
Enter a:<1>
Enter b:<2>
```

The first `<` satisfies the first `%c`; the `1` matches the `%d`, the `>` matches the second `%c`, so all is fine so far.

The second lot of input, though, reads the newline from the first line into the first `%c`, then fails to convert the `<` to an integer and stops, leaving the `<` for the next input to process.

The `Enter c:` prompt is given, but the `<2>` is processed because it is in the correct format, so the `Enter d:` prompt is given.

There are multiple ways to fix this, including:

1. Insert a blank before the first `%c` in the format strings.  This will skip white space, including newlines, and give you the expected behaviour.  It is probably the simplest fix.
2. Read lines and use `sscanf()` to process them.  This is generally the best solution.  (Use `fgets()` to read the line.)

In either case, check that the `scanf()` family function returns the correct value (3).  And use two variables `int c1, c2;` to read the characters and validate that the user typed what you require.

A bare minimum fixup is:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    char c1, c2;
    printf("Enter a: ");
    if (scanf(" %c%d%c", &c1, &a, &c2) != 3 || c1 != '<' || c2 != '>')
        fprintf(stderr, "Bogus input!\n"), exit(1);
    printf("Enter b: ");
    if (scanf(" %c%d%c", &c1, &b, &c2) != 3 || c1 != '<' || c2 != '>')
        fprintf(stderr, "Bogus input!\n"), exit(1);
    printf("Enter c: ");
    if (scanf(" %c%d%c", &c1, &c, &c2) != 3 || c1 != '<' || c2 != '>')
        fprintf(stderr, "Bogus input!\n"), exit(1);
    printf("Enter d: ");
    if (scanf(" %c%d%c", &c1, &d, &c2) != 3 || c1 != '<' || c2 != '>')
        fprintf(stderr, "Bogus input!\n"), exit(1);
    double ans;
    ans=(a*b/c + c*d/a)/(b*a/c + d*b/a);
    ans=fabs(ans);
    printf("Formula 1 result = <%lf>\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm being lazy with the comma operators after the `if` statement.  It would be better, though, to use a function to manage the inputs:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void get_number(int *var, const char *name)
{
    char c1, c2;
    printf("Enter %s: ", name);
    if (scanf(" %c%d%c", &c1, var, &c2) != 3 || c1 != '<' || c2 != '>')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bogus input!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    get_number(&a, "a");
    get_number(&b, "b");
    get_number(&c, "c");
    get_number(&d, "d");

    double ans;
    ans=(a*b/c + c*d/a)/(b*a/c + d*b/a);
    ans=fabs(ans);
    printf("Formula 1 result = <%lf>\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

And better still to use:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int get_number(const char *name)
{
    char buffer[4096];

    printf("Enter %s: ", name);
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EOF or error on input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char c1, c2;
    int val;
    if (sscanf(buffer, " %c%d%c", &c1, &val, &c2) != 3 || c1 != '<' || c2 != '>')
    {
        /* buffer contains a newline unless you typed more than 4095 characters before the newline */
        fprintf(stderr, "Bogus input (does not match <number>): %s", buffer);
        exit(1);
    }
    return val;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = get_number("a");
    int b = get_number("b");
    int c = get_number("c");
    int d = get_number("d");
    double ans = fabs((a*b/c + c*d/a) / (b*a/c + d*b/a));
    printf("Inputs: a = %d, b = %d, c = %d, d = %d\n", a, b, c, d);
    printf("Formula 1 result = <%lf>\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Note how the code uses `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` which means that the error message can tell the user what they entered that was not what was expected.  It also uses the function to return the value, leading to the simpler code shown.  And the output includes the input values for inspection.  That may not be needed for your submission system, but it surely helps you while you're developing the code.

You can work on the upgrade to process `double` values as inputs; it isn't hard.

Comment: You probably meant `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.  On VMS, `exit(1)` indicates success to the operating system.

Comment: @M.M: No, I was deliberately, but not explicitly, discounting VMS and MVS and some other arcane systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
double ans;
ans=(a*b/c + c*d/a)/(b*a/c + d*b/a);
```

The C language doesn't take into account what you do with a result when it determines its type. So the fact that you assign the results of this operation to a `double` don't have any effect on the way the result is computed, it just converts the integer result to a double. When you divide integers by integers, you get integer division.

You could do something like this:

```
ans=(a*1.0*b/c + c*1.0*d/a)/(b*1.0*a/c + d*1.0*b/a);
```

The multiplication by a non-integer forces non-integer multiplication, addition, and division to be used.

Comment: that was my next question you answered it before i ask!!